# Clone div and change id of selects inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I use this code to clone the `.minor` `div` inside the `.major` `div`:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".clone", clone);

cloneIndex = 1;

function clone() {
    cloneIndex++;
    $(this).parents(".minor").clone()
           .appendTo(".major")
           .attr("id", "form" + cloneIndex);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="major">
    <p>
      <select id="major_sel_id">
        <option value="na">N/a</option>
        <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
      </select>
      Major Select id
    </p>
  <div class="minor" id="form1">
    <p>
      <select id="form1_q1">
        <option value="y">Yes</option>
        <option value="n">No</option>
        <option value="na" selected>N/a</option>
      </select>
      Question 1
    </p>
    <p>
      <select id="form1_q2">
        <option value="y">Yes</option>
        <option value="n">No</option>
        <option value="na" selected>N/a</option>
      </select>
      Question 2
    </p>
    <p>
      <button id="add" type="button" class="clone">+</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

However this keeps the same IDs in each select.
How can I change the IDs of the selects to `form2_q1`, `form2_q2`, etc...?

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0yLr3hjj/2/)

Comment: Please insert code in https://jsfiddle.net
because code not work for me

Comment: looks like you need to add .prop() to clone and pass in a new id.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0yLr3hjj/2/

Comment: @Jared care to paste an example/solution?

Comment: Code that generates `id` values dynamically could often just do without those `id` attributes. Explain why you need the `id` attributes?

Comment: Are you sure you need ids?

Comment: Yes.  I will need to get the values later in a c# template by id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You succeeded in replacing the ID of the parent, you need to get the children and replace their IDs. To get the children, you can use `find("select")`, and to replace their IDs, you can use a function inside `attr()` which will add the current suffix to the string `"form" + cloneIndex`. To get the current suffix, you can use `this.id.substring(5)`.

Try this (I added `console.log` line for demo, you don't need it):

```js
cloneIndex = 1;

function clone() {
  cloneIndex++;
  $(this).parents(".minor")
         .clone()
         .attr("id", "form" + cloneIndex)
         .appendTo(".major")
         .find("select")
         .attr("id", function() {
      return "form" + cloneIndex + this.id.substring(5);
    });
  console.log($(".major").html());
}

$("#add").click(clone);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="major">
  <p>
    <select id="major_sel_id">
        <option value="na">N/a</option>
        <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
      </select> Major Select id
  </p>
  <div class="minor" id="form1">
    <p>
      <select id="form1_q1">
        <option value="y">Yes</option>
        <option value="n">No</option>
        <option value="na" selected>N/a</option>
      </select> Question 1
    </p>
    <p>
      <select id="form1_q2">
        <option value="y">Yes</option>
        <option value="n">No</option>
        <option value="na" selected>N/a</option>
      </select> Question 2
    </p>
    <p>
      <button id="add" type="button" class="clone">+</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to replace all the selects ids too:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".clone", clone);

let cloneIndex = 1;

function clone() {
    cloneIndex++;
    $(this).parents(".minor").clone()
           .appendTo(".major")
           .attr("id", "form" + cloneIndex)
           .find("select").each(function(i, s) {
               $(s).attr("id", $(s).attr("id").replace(/form\d+/, "form" + cloneIndex));
           });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="major">
    <p>
      <select id="major_sel_id">
        <option value="na">N/a</option>
        <option value="test1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="test2">Test 2</option>
      </select>
      Major Select id
    </p>
  <div class="minor" id="form1">
    <p>
      <select id="form1_q1">
        <option value="y">Yes</option>
        <option value="n">No</option>
        <option value="na" selected>N/a</option>
      </select>
      Question 1
    </p>
    <p>
      <select id="form1_q2">
        <option value="y">Yes</option>
        <option value="n">No</option>
        <option value="na" selected>N/a</option>
      </select>
      Question 2
    </p>
    <p>
      <button id="add" type="button" class="clone">+</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: +1 I thought of `replace()`, but then decided to go with the simpler and more performant `substring()`. However, you don't need `each()`, simply use a function for the value of `attr()` like I did.